# Android view behind Navigation Bar behavior, how to fix?

Tags: android, motorola, xiaomi

so, I've head a lot of answers here regarding problems with both the status bar and the navigation bar. The app I'm currently working on has to fit behind the status bar, but not the navigation bar, since it uses the BottomBar as it's main navigation.

So, I've tried setting `<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>`, and setting this to `false` just changes the tint of the controls, the content stills being drawn behind it.

Removing `window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)` disables both the content behind the Status Bar and the Navigation Bar. So no go...

Toggling `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` doesn't solve the problem...

I tried to detect if the Navigation Bar is visible, but so far I didn't succeed, as even when not visible, the `resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android")` will still return a value as if the bar is displaying. And the attribute `config_showNavigationBar`, only works when the device has physical keys (like Samsung, for example)

I'm testing on a Moto X4 (Pie) and an Xiaomi Note 6 Pro (Oreo), by enabling the navigation with gestures to hide the Navigation Bar.

Prints (Xiaomi top, X4 bottom):

---

1) Behavior out of the box:

[image: Tabs behind the Navigation Bar]

---

2) When getting NavBar height and applying custom margin to BottomBar:

[image: Added custom margin to the BottomBar, so it appears above the Navigation Bar]

---

3) Undesired behavior when gesture mode is enabled:

[image: The black bar stays, because I can't listen for any property that hints if the Navigation Bar is actually there]

---

4) Expected behavior when gesture mode is enabled:

[image: The black bar should be hidden, because some property signaled that the navigation controls are not there]

Comment: You found a solution?

Comment: @PramodGarg Unfortunately, no...